# Cannot transfer a great admiral to another city

Tags: civilization-6

I have a great admiral which has spawned in my harbour district. I cannot transfer him to another city. The option is greyed out.

There is another city close by with a harbour district.

However, the city I really want to transfer him to is in another body of water which is cut off from where he is.

All cities have harbour district and harbour improvements.

I did not choose where he spawned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As obvious as it is or is not. When the admiral spawns, it was in this case, it was a harbour district. (this was during my first game, so I am now well aware of this shift of units preferring districts when producing)

Once I moved the admiral to a city, I then had the option enabled to transfer to another city.

Much the same as if building a naval unit that if a coastal city has a harbour district, the unit is built there.

Note, you need a city on the coast to be able to move the great admiral.

Comment: Just want to add to that the admiral can also spawn on a harbor district in a lake. That makes things difficult if you've done so.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround allowing to move your great admiral as if it was a land unit:

1. Open the file "Units.xml" (it is located in ..\Base\Assets\Gameplay\Data\Units.xml)
2. Make a copy of Units.xml if you like to play it safe
3. Go to the line with *UnitType="UNIT_GREAT_ADMIRAL"* in the section "Units"
4. Change "DOMAIN_SEA" to "DOMAIN_LAND"
5. Start or restart the Civilization VI and load your save game
6. Be aware that you won't see the change until the next turn

Source: https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/bug-great-admiral-spawned-in-a-lake-and-cannot-leave.603207/#post-14850070